# rosjava publisher and subscriber in the same node

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I take a single node (a class that extends **AbstractNodeMain**) and I include both publishers and a subscriber, the subscriber does not seem to receive any information that I publish to its topic with rostopic.

I was trying to merge both the Listener and Talker examples into a single entity that publishes using the **executeCancellableLoop** and subscribes to a topic with the **addMessageListener** method. My goal is to write a robot driver that publishes sensor data at the same time that it listens for movement commands. Can this be done?

If I avoid adding the subscriber the publisher works fine, and viceversa. If I add both things, the publisher works fine but the subscriber doesn't read any data, although the topic appears in the output of rostopic list.

I am using ROS Fuerte with the Python roscore.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35101/rosjava-publisher-and-subscriber-in-the-same-node/) by [jpiramirez](https://answers.ros.org/users/2480/jpiramirez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2012-05-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-05-29**:
Could you share some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I moved my development from an x86 machine to a 64-bit one, running Ubuntu Precise and ROS Fuerte. My logging messages inside the subscriber started showing up on the rxconsole, so this is solved.

---

Originally posted by [jpiramirez](https://answers.ros.org/users/2480/jpiramirez/) with karma: 141 on 2012-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0